# What's the best way to create a huffman encoder/decoder without using premade STL libraris?

Tags: c++, data-structures, huffman-code

Basically i want to make my own huffman encoder/decoder but I do not want to use STL libraries (priority queues (heaps), stacks, vectors, etc).

I know that i will have to implement SOME data structures but since I am writing them all myself i want to know what ones are easy to write and will do the job for huffman encoding? I feel like a minHeap might be all i need to sort the subtrees, but obviously i need to somehow create the trees via some linked list structure.

So what are the data structures that are necessary for a huffman encoder?

P.s. any links that talk about how to create the codebook for huffmann is greatly appreciated also.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't know what data structures are "easy" to write, then you shouldn't be writing any data structures.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use STL.

Comment: What you are asking is so opposite to what any engineer would have thought, might as well start writing your own compiler straight from hand-crafted assembly. At least clarify why you want to waste your time writing everything from scratch.

Comment: Programming assingment for my data structures class. The professor is a nutjob and with only a week left before the final decided we need another freaking assingment. Also he never lets you use any STL libraries because its a data structures class and you are meant to make your own.

Comment: You can do it with only arrays.

Comment: A C version at http://www.programminglogic.com/implementing-huffman-coding-in-c/ should give you a good start. Don't copy it, though, that's plagiarism